# Cakephp 4 Method "session()" does not exist

Tags: session, cakephp-4.x

I have an issue related to session in cakephp 4 , it return "session doesnt exist" , the same function work well in cakephp 3 , I checked the cookbook and didn't find any new changes about the Session.

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$name = $session->read('User.name');
```

Error

```
2020-05-19 17:45:55 Error: [BadMethodCallException] Method "session()" does not exist in xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php on line 604
Stack Trace:
- xxxxxxx//src/Controller/UsersController.php:135
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:521
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:79
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:229
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php:124
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:159
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:137
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:162
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:119
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- xxxxxxx//vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- xxxxxxx//webroot/index.php:40
```

Comment: @ndn any idea ?

Comment: I tried this $this->getRequest()->getSession() and it works , may be it will help someone else

Comment: All of the old combined getter/setter methods are gone in v4, replaced with separate get and set versions. This is well documented in the release notes.

Answer (score 2):

In Cake 3, We use

> $this->request->session();

In Cake 4, Cake changes the calling method and now it is

> $this->request->getSession()

Details: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object